# How to use grouping by XXX, and using aggregate funtion correctly? WITH MIN VALUES

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch records from 4 tables by using joins. These tables are rates, carriers, depots and margin. I am able to get the records that needed from this 4 table, but when I am using a group by and aggregate function (MIN), my min sell column is correct, however, the other data such as carrierID, depotID and ratesID are different.

I have OriginType (OT) and DestinatioType (DT)and there are 2 cases for each; Depot and Door. So when I group them, I get four options as (services):

- Depot To Depot
- Depot To Door
- Door To Depot
- Door To Door

I am trying to fetch the min(rates) as 'Sell' for each of these service and display it. The Sell is calculated as:

1. autoRate table as A has a column Buy, carrier, OT, DT, Origin (*Value: Canberra*), Destination (*Value: Melbourne*) and Car (*Value :4WD/Van*)
2. Left Join with carriers as C with `A.carrier = C.ID`
3. C.Fuellevy column as Percentage `((C.FuelLevy * A.buy) + C.FuelLevy)` as EQ1
4. `((EQ1 * 10%) + EQ1)` as EQ2
5. EQ2 price for each row with have a Margin table Percentage. For example, if the EQ2 value is 400, then It will look in the Margin table, find the range (low and high as 350(low) and 500(high)) and its percentage is 25%, so `((EQ2 * 25%)+ EQ2)` gives the sell value.

I am not too sure how to upload my data and database table here, so I tried to explain here what I want.

> the query I build is:-

```
Select   Depo.*,  DL.id as DepoID,  DL.carrier as CarNo, DL.depotCity, DL.depoSuburb, min(Depo.Sell)  as sellcost , Depo.OriginType as OT From (
    Select Mar.*,  M.MarginPer, round((eq2 * M.MarginPer) + eq2)as Sell   From (
                        Select GST.* , EQ1 as 'FinalEQ1' , round((EQ1 * .10) + EQ1,2) as eq2 From (
                                Select A.ID as RateID, A.Origin, A.OriginState, A.Destination, A.DestinationState, A.Carrier as RateCarrier, A.Car as CarType, A.Buy as Buy, A.OriginType, A.DestinationType ,
                                C.ID as CarrierID, C.Carrier, C.FuelLevy , round((A.buy * C.FuelLevy) + A.Buy, 2) As EQ1,
                                CONCAT(A.OriginType, ' to ' ,A.DestinationType ) as service,
                                 D.id as DepoID,  D.carrier as CarNo, D.depotCity, D.depoSuburb
                                from carrier C
                                left join autorates A on A.carrier = C.ID
                                left join dList D on D.carrier =  C.ID
                                where A.origin = 'Canberra' and A.destination = 'Melbourne' and A.car = '4WD/Van'  AND  D.carrier = A.carrier AND A.goodsAllowed =  0
                                AND C.Disabled = 0
                                AND D.depotCity  = 'Canberra'
                                 order by  EQ1
                            ) As GST
                        order by  eq2
             ) As Mar
             Left Join margin M on Mar.eq2 >=  M.low and  Mar.eq2 <= M.high
                   order by  Sell
        ) As Depo
            Left  Join dList DL  on DL.Carrier = Depo.RateCarrier
            Where DL.depotCity = 'Melbourne'
             group by OT
             order by  sellcost
```

Results before the Group by and MIN():-
[image]

As we see the sellcost value 412 and the carNo is 51 here

[image]

And in this screenshot, the carrierno has changed, but the the MIN value remains the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other data is different"? You mean you're not getting the carrier with the minimum value of the column? If you select other columns while grouping, it gets that column from a random row in the group, not necessarily the one with the `MIN()`. To understand why, imagine if you have two aggregation functions, e.g. both MIN and MAX. Which row would you expect it to get other columns from? Or what if it's something like AVG, which isn't even from a specific row?

Comment: To add to Barmar's comment, MIN and MAX are not even necessarily from specific rows. Even if MySQL was kind enough to try giving you the row values accompanying the MIN you calculate (if you're only calculating a MIN), there are too many situations where you could have numerous rows with that value.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am not getting the correct values of the carriers. When I get the results I get the MIN value of the sell but the carriers are different. I get the next row of each group values where as MIN value I get are all correct

Comment: This is why most SQL databases don't even allow you to select columns that aren't in `GROUP BY`. MySQL has the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode that controls whether it's allowed.

Comment: @Barmar how do I use then `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?

Comment: It's a SQL mode that you set, it will cause your query to get an error because you're violating the rule.

Comment: If you want to find out how to get the row you're looking for, see the linked question.

Comment: @Barmar I have read the answer linked to question, and what I assume that the table has already some values. But in my case, I am calculating the values and then I am trying to get the min values after doing some calculations

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0 you can put the query that calculates the values in a CTE, then use the methods in the linked question to get the row with the min value. If you're using an older version, I suggest you put the calculated values into a temporary table and getting the row with the min value.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I am not too sure, how to create a temp table?

Comment: Google how to use proper `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Barmar i have tried few options, and one of them was working on one table only to find the MIN(buy), but what I see that whenever I use the MIN function and group by service, it shows all wrong results. My MIN values are correct but the values in the same row do not match with the MIN buy price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just managed the get query. This will Work as I have tested on my SQL-WB

```
SELECT DepoD.*, DL2.id, DL2.carrier AS a, DL2.depotCity
    , DL2.depoSuburb AS 'PickupSub', MIN(Sell) AS sellcost 
FROM ( 
    SELECT Depo.*, DL.id AS DepoID, DL.carrier AS CarNo, DL.depotCity, DL.depoSuburb AS 'PickupSub'
        , DL.depoSuburb AS 'DestSub', MIN(Sell) AS sellcost, Depo.OriginType AS OT 
    FROM (
        SELECT Mar.*, M.MarginPer, MIN(round((eq2 * M.MarginPer) + eq2)) AS Sell 
        FROM (
            SELECT GST.*, EQ1 AS 'FinalEQ1', MIN(round((EQ1 * .10) + EQ1, 2)) AS eq2 
            FROM (
                SELECT A.ID AS RateID, A.Origin, A.OriginState, A.Destination, A.DestinationState
                    , A.Carrier AS RateCarrier, A.Car AS CarType, A.Buy AS Buy,  A.OriginType
                    , A.DestinationType, C.ID AS CarrierID, C.Carrier, C.FuelLevy
                    , round((A.buy * C.FuelLevy) + A.Buy, 2) AS EQ1
                    , CONCAT(A.OriginType, ' to ', A.DestinationType ) AS service 
                FROM carrier C
                LEFT JOIN autorates A ON A.carrier = C.ID
                WHERE A.origin = 'Melbourne' 
                    AND A.destination = 'Canberra' 
                    AND A.car = '4WD/Van' 
                    AND A.goodsAllowed = 0
                    AND C.Disabled = 0
                ORDER BY EQ1 ASC
            ) AS GST
            GROUP BY service, CarrierID
            ORDER BY eq2
        ) AS Mar
        LEFT JOIN margin M ON Mar.eq2 >= M.low AND Mar.eq2 <= M.high
        GROUP BY service
        ORDER BY Sell
    ) AS Depo
    LEFT JOIN dList AS DL ON DL.Carrier = Depo.RateCarrier
    WHERE DL.depotCity IN('Melbourne', 'Canberra') 
    GROUP BY carrier, service
    ORDER BY sellcost
) AS DepoD
LEFT JOIN dList DL2 ON DL2.Carrier = DepoD.RateCarrier
WHERE DL2.depotCity IN('Melbourne', 'Canberra') 
GROUP BY carrier, service
ORDER BY sellcost
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *Not a final answer, but a query to test and see if this part works. If so, I'll provide the rest of the query.*

---

If you break the problem down, I think what you have to do is to identify the lowest Sell for each combination of OriginType and DestinationType. Then join to the tables to get the matching rows.

The query below doesn't get all of the detail info, but it should get the rows with the lowest Sell value. If it works, then I can add to the query to get the other, matching data.

One aspect that question is the use of `LEFT JOIN`. That might include rows that do not match up with the `ON` clauses, essentially adding columns with null values. This might impact performance, and using just a `JOIN` might work better. If you test this and it works as stated below, run it again without the `LEFT` that is in front of each of the `JOIN` clauses. If you get the same results, let me know in the comments.

Give it a try and see if you get the four values for each of the combinations of OriginType and DestinationType. If it does, I'll update the answer with the rest of the query.

```
SELECT
    A.OriginType,
    A.DestinationType,
    round(A.buy * (1.0 + C.FuelLevy), 2) AS EQ1,
    round(round(A.buy * (1.0 + C.FuelLevy), 2) * 1.10, 2) AS eq2,
    MIN(round((eq2 * (1.0 + M.MarginPer)))) AS Sell
FROM carrier C
LEFT JOIN autorates A
    ON A.carrier = C.ID
LEFT JOIN dList D
    ON D.carrier = A.carrier
LEFT JOIN margin M
    ON round(round(A.buy * (1.0 + C.FuelLevy), 2) * 1.10, 2) BETWEEN M.low AND M.high
WHERE A.origin = 'Canberra'
    AND A.destination = 'Melbourne'
    AND A.car = '4WD/Van'
    AND A.goodsAllowed =  0
    AND C.Disabled = 0
    AND D.depotCity  = 'Canberra'
GROUP BY LOWER(A.OriginType), LOWER(A.DestinationType)
ORDER BY Sell
```

Comment: seems there us an error. Unknow column eq2 in field list. Thanks for your help

Comment: Replace `eq2` in `MIN(round((eq2...)))` with the formula on the previous line. You can't refer to an alias in the same `SELECT` list.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Good catch.